How to change UISearchController SearchBar height?
I have a custom view called MySearchBar. It's comprised of a UIStackView with various buttons and images. The stackView has translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to false and a heightAnchor constraint set to 44. In order to add it to the UISearchBar inside of a UISearchController, I set searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.isHidden = true and then add MySearchBar as a subview of the searchControllers searchBar. This works great with the UISearchController animations and gives me a bunch of flexibility. However, I can't get the height of the overall search bar to be what I want. It's currently 56px tall, but I would like it to be 44px tall. I've tried setting the frame and using constraints but neither works. Is there any methods that would work? I think it might have some thing to do with setting the height of _UISearchBarSearchContainerView.

